# Format a telephone number using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have phone numbers stored in a database using char(10), and they look for example as `4155551212`.

I wish a Twig template to display them as `(415) 555-1212`.

How is this best accomplished?

Comment: Use `substr()`...? This is easy. Use your imagination!

Comment: Create twig extension - http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen.  There is no `substr()`, but I think `slice` will work.

Comment: @u_mulder  I've never created an extension on only used macros, but will give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: @u_mulder  I don't think your link applies to Twig without Symfony.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be nice not to have to add this filter every time, but it will meet my needs.

```
<?php
require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
try {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true,));
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('phone', function ($num) {
        return ($num)?'('.substr($num,0,3).') '.substr($num,3,3).'-'.substr($num,6,4):'&nbsp;';
    }));
    echo $twig->render('filter.html', array('phone'=>'4155551212'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

filter.html

```
{{ phone|phone }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it in Symfony.

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension {
    public function getFilters() {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('phone', [$this, 'phoneFilter']),
        ];
    }

    public function phoneFilter($phoneNumber) {
        if (substr($phoneNumber, 0, 2) == "+1") {
            return preg_replace("/(\+1)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", "$1 ($2) $3-$4", $phoneNumber);
        }
        return preg_replace("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", "($1) $2-$3", $phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$numberPhone = '4155551212';
$firstChain = substr($numberPhone, 0, 3);
$secondChain = substr($numberPhone, 3, 3);
$thirdChain = substr($numberPhone, 6, 4);
$formatedNumberPhone = '(' . $firstChain . ') ' . $secondChain . '-' . $thirdChain;

echo $formatedNumberPhone;
```

Here is the solution for those who have similar question about it.

Little bit explaination about how substr() works :

It take three arguments in this case :

1. The chain you want to modify
2. The index which represent the place where the function will begin his process
3. How many caracters you want to preserve

Note that you can pass negative value to the second and third argument (go to official doc for further information).

In this case, I am taking the first caracter of the phone number, so I'll tell the function to begin from 0 and to keep 3 caracters, so it looks like I did : `susbtr($numberPhone, 0, 3)`.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know how to do it with PHP and do it the same way as you, but not with Twig.

Comment: I never used Twig, I though you could do this in php in order to avoid some complex reaserch !

Comment: Yea, I know, but the whole point of Twig is to separate the view from the logic.

Comment: My own home spun MVC framework, and I am being generous calling it a framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
Eu fiz assim: {{ p.number[:4] }} - {{ p.number[4:]}}
I did that way: {{ p.number[:4] }} - {{ p.number[4:]}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Phone Number in US Format  : {{phone_number | phone | default("-")}}

Comment: Unknown "phone" filter

Comment: @MohammadFareed, are you using a filter for a particular framework / CMS?